# Difference between int* a and int* a =new int

Tags: c++

I m studying Binary Search Tree just had little Doubt, here is struct to construct a node.

```
struct Node 

    { 
        int data; 
        Node* left, *right; 
    };
```

Now My doubt is when I m creating a new node why do I have to write

```
Node* node =new Node;
```

Why not

```
Node* node;
```

Comment: If this is a C++ question, you might want to tag it with C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Node* node;
```

You define a pointer, but the pointer points to nothing.

```
Node* node =new Node
```

You define a pointer and a Node object, and make the pointer point to the object.

Answer (score 0):

```
Node* node
```

this is a pointer which is *just* declared.

Accessing this pointer may give your garbage.

If you want to make pointer point to **your own node object**, you do by

1. creating new node object
2. assign a pointer to it so that you can reference this node later in code using the node pointer like this `Node* node = new Node;`

Hope this clears!